# what method will called when we start to rotate device and after it finished

Tags: ios, ipad, methods, rotation

i want to detect a rotation process on ipad programmatically. In this case i want to set a boolean into yes, when the rotation will begin, and set it false after the rotation did ending. Is there any method that called when the rotation will begin and the rotation did ending?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

From Apple Docs:

*Sent to the view controller just before the user interface begins rotating.*

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

*Sent to the view controller after the user interface rotates:*

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
```

See more here: [UIViewController Class Reference -> Responding to View Rotation Events](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

**ATTENTION:**
This is deprecated, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25965511/1953914)

Comment: This is now deprecated

Comment: willRotate works for me in iOS 9 (Xamarin). However, please look at @wyzkid207 post and use viewWillTransitionToSize

Answer (score 29):

For newcomers to this post, the methods suggested by Nekto have become deprecated in iOS 8. Apple suggests to use:

```
-(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
```

You can use the "size" parameter as an easy way to get whether it is transitioning to portrait or landscape.

i.e.

```
if (size.width > size.height)
{
    // Position elements for Landscape
}
else
{
    // Position elements for Portrait
}
```

More info is availablein the [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIContentContainer_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIContentContainer/viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:).

Comment: Size is rather useless if the view of your controller has a fixed width/height in either layout.

Comment: This is true. I just was giving a quick down and dirty possible example.

Comment: use             UIInterfaceOrientation destinationOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

Answer (score 25):

All the above methods(in the answer by @Nekto)  are deprecated in iOS8.0 and later versions. Source: [iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/)

> **As of iOS 8, all rotation-related methods are deprecated**. Instead,
>   rotations are treated as a change in the size of the view controller’s
>   view and are therefore reported using the
>   viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator: method. When the
>   interface orientation changes, UIKit calls this method on the window’s
>   root view controller. That view controller then notifies its child
>   view controllers, propagating the message throughout the view
>   controller hierarchy.

In iOS8 or later you can use the below method.

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id <UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];

    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {

        // Stuff you used to do in willRotateToInterfaceOrientation would go here.
        // If you don't need anything special, you can set this block to nil.

    } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {

        // Stuff you used to do in didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation would go here.
        // If not needed, set to nil.

    }];
}
```

Comment: this is a great answer:)

Comment: i'm going to save this

Comment: this answer is the best

Answer (score 2):

SWIFT 5:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { _ in
        // code at start of rotation
    }) { _ in
        // code at end of rotation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the UISplitViewController protocol, the new method for iOS8 is

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willChangeToDisplayMode:(UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode)displayMode
```

There are four display modes:

```
typedef enum UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode : NSInteger {
  UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAutomatic,
  UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden,
  UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible,
  UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryOverlay,
} UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode;
```

**BUT** this method will **NEVER** return Automatic.