# How to correctly work with UIScrollView and UIPageControl?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I have a `UIScrollView` that I would like to use with a `UIPageControl` to have different pages to swipe horizontally. I need to add a `UITextView` and a number of `UIImageView` for every page.
In my `ViewController` I call a webservice and, when data arrive, I add items as follows:

```
for(int i=0;i<[arrData count];i++) {
    NSString *body=@"Dummy text";

    CGRect frame;

    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size.width = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    frame.size.height = 40; //vedere landscape

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [label setText:body];
    label.numberOfLines=0;
    [label sizeToFit];
    label.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self.scrollView addSubview:label];

    [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:label];
    int y_pos=label.frame.size.height+10;
    int x_pos=0;
    for(int img=0; img<[[[arrData objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"images"] count]; img++) {
        NSString *imageURL=[[[[arrData objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"images"] objectAtIndex:img] objectForKey:@"fn"];

        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i+img*100, y_pos, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];

    }

}
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * [arrData count], self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
```

It runs fine in portrait, but when the device is rotated, obviously, the layout is ruined ... which is the best way to work with a `ScrollView` with `PageControl`? Do I have to handle rotation and change the distance between the inserted items or (as I think) is there a better way to build everything?

Comment: Are you using autolayout? If you are, use constraints instead of setting the frame. Or else you would have to handle rotation if you want full control over the layout (setting the frame to new values when you rotate). I am using autolayout with scrollview in pagecontrol and rotation works fine (no extra code needed).

Comment: Actually i am not using autolayout.

Comment: And what do you mean the layout is ruined? Do the frames you set get changed? Or is it doing what is it supposed to (frames stay the same) but it looks bad?

Comment: The frames stay the same; when i go to landscape i see the first frame and a part of the second frame

Comment: The best way would be to use autolayout, but if you can't, then recalculating the frames would give you the most customization. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443943/what-method-will-called-when-we-start-to-rotate-device-and-after-it-finished

Answer (score 1):

yes you have to set your scrollviews frame again every time orientation changes, because flexible width stretches the width of scrollview from both sides in landscape mode,so its contents get overlapped and causes problem when you have horizontal scrolling. one thing you can do is set you scrollview's auto resizing mask to flexibleRightMargin|flexibleLeftMargin. it will keep the contents of your scrollview at the center but scrolling will not look clean.